# I want to make a directory inaccessible

Tags: directory

I would like to make a directory inaccessible, but still be able to open documents in that same directory from within my application.
So a domain user that logs in to the application has read rigths on this directory so he can open documents that are located in this directory.
But I want him to get an inaccessible message if he wants to get to this directory by the Explorer.
Is this possible?

Regards
Jborghans

Comment: Which Operating system?

Comment: windows  server 2008 R2